# Print line that meets conditions in different lines with awk

Tags: awk

total newbie. It is possible with awk to print the following:

```
w171930 t1 Y z2545377 <--- print this line
w171930 t2 X z4495648
w171931 t1 Y z2555698 <--- print this line
w171931 t2 X z5505690
w171932 t1 Y z2554345 <--- print this line
w171932 t2 X z5507345
w171933 t1 Y z2214694
w171933 t2 Y z8022710
w171933 t3 Y z2143462
w171933 t4 Y z6217556
w171933 t5 Y z9608343
w171933 t6 Y z9984446
w171933 t7 Y z2985572
w171933 t8 Y z6334512 <--- print this line
w171933 t9 X z6503375
w171943 t1 Y z2441603 <--- NO print this line
w171943 t2 X z4644534
w171943 t3 Y z2164440
w171944 t1 Y z2165532
```

**Search on $3 == "X" and print the previous line if the next line has a $2 == "t1"**

**Goal**

```
w171930 t1 Y z2545377
w171931 t1 Y z2555698
w171932 t1 Y z2554345
w171933 t8 Y z6334512
```

I have only managed to print the previous line but I don't know how to perform the complete condition

```
awk '$3 == "Y" { Y=$0; next; } { if ($3 =="X") print Y;}'
```

I'm sorry if I don't express myself correctly

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution with `awk`:

```sh
$ awk '$2=="t1" && third=="X"{print line2}
       {line2=line1; line1=$0; third=$3}' ip.txt
w171930 t1 Y z2545377
w171931 t1 Y z2555698
w171932 t1 Y z2554345
w171933 t8 Y z6334512
```

- `line1` will have the previous line and `line2` will have previous but one line
- `third` saves the 3rd field content of the previous line
- when the current line's 2nd field is `t1`, check if previous line's 3rd field is `X` and if so, print previous but one line

Comment: your solution suggets me this one:
`awk '$2 == "t1" {if (key == "X") print a_copy}
     {a_copy=prev;prev=$0;key=$3}' file` where we print a copy of previous line.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your requirement:

```
Search on $3 == "X" and print the previous line if the next line has a $2 == "t1"
```

As in life, in software it's much easier to do things based on what HAS happened rather than what WILL happen, so don't write requirements based on what the NEXT thing will be, write them based on what the PREVIOUS things were and you'll find it much easier to conceptualize and write the code to implement them. In this case your requirement should be written as:

```
If $2 == "t1" in the current line and $3 == "X" in the previous line then print the line before that.
```

which leads to the obvious implementation:

```
$ awk '($2=="t1") && (p3=="X") {print pp0} {pp0=p0; p0=$0; p3=$3}' file
w171930 t1 Y z2545377 <--- print this line
w171931 t1 Y z2555698 <--- print this line
w171932 t1 Y z2554345 <--- print this line
w171933 t8 Y z6334512 <--- print this line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2=="t1"{ if(prev2!="" && prev!="") print prev2 }
     { prev=($3=="X"?prev2:""); prev2=$0 }' input
```

- `$2=="t1"` only for lines where the second element = "t1". When `prev` and `prev2` have a value, then we should print the value.
- `prev` will contain the value of `prev2` when the third element is equal to "X"
- `prev2` will have the value of the line which needs to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/SCl59z/1) if desired which can be done in Perl:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'while (/^.*\R(?=(?:\S+\s){2}X\s\S+\R\S+\st1)/gm) {print $&}' file
```

Or, with slight modification to the regex, you can use GNU Grep:

```
grep -ozP '.*\R(?=(?:\S+\s){2}X\s\S+\R\S+\st1)' file | tr -d '\000'
```

Or `ruby`:

```
ruby -e 'puts $<.read.scan(/(.*\R)(?=(?:\S+\s){2}X\s\S+\R\S+\st1)/)' file
```

Any of those (with your example input) prints:

```
w171930 t1 Y z2545377 <--- print this line
w171931 t1 Y z2555698 <--- print this line
w171932 t1 Y z2554345 <--- print this line
w171933 t8 Y z6334512 <--- print this line
```

Comment: The `tr -d '\000'` deletes the `NUL` line endings inserted by GNU grep.

Answer (score 0):

slightly verbose, but it gets the job done :

```
<<<"${aa}" mawk '

 BEGIN {
       _+=++_
 } {
     do {____=$((__=$_)<"") 

     } while($(_+getline)=="Y")
   
     if(___<("X"==$++_)) {

       printf("%s%.*s",____,\
           (___=__!="t1")<_,ORS) }; -—_}'

w171930 t1 Y z2545377
w171931 t1 Y z2555698
w171932 t1 Y z2554345
w171933 t8 Y z6334512
```